Binding a collection to a WPF ListBox using ReactiveUI
I'm learning ReactiveUI at the moment, and I'm struggling to figure out how to bind a collection to a ListBox in WPF. I already understand the MVVM pattern, and I was able to do this very thing in MVVM Light some years ago, but ReactiveUI is proving more difficult. I haven't been able to find too many simple examples, just convoluted ones that don't do a great job at demonstrating the basics. Also, a lot of the answers I've found on Stack Overflow are very old, so they don't use the new Dynamic Data libraries that ReactiveUI recommends nowadays.
I'm working in a very simple WPF application while I try to learn the ropes.
I have a simple view called ListBoxView:
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="MvvmSandbox.Views.ListBoxView"
             x:TypeArguments="vm:ListBoxViewModel"
             xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmSandbox.ViewModels"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmSandbox.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <ListBox x:Name="Strings" />
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>

Here's the code-behind:
using MvvmSandbox.ViewModels;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace MvvmSandbox.Views
{
    public partial class ListBoxView : ReactiveUserControl<ListBoxViewModel>
    {
        public ListBoxView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new ListBoxViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Strings, v => v.Strings.ItemsSource);
            });
        }
    }
}

And here's the view model:
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MvvmSandbox.ViewModels
{
    public class ListBoxViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Strings => _strings;
        private ObservableCollection<string> _strings;

        public ListBoxViewModel()
        {
            _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "This is a test of the Emergency Broadcast System.",
                "This is only a test."
            };
        }
    }
}

The view does come out with the items, but they're collapsed to their minimum height and don't display the strings themselves; you can see the blue bounding box for the first item here.

I'm not the best at ReactiveUI (or even WPF), so I simplified a bit by converting the 'control' to a 'mainwindow'. Your problem seeing the output might just be that you didn't set the collection as the itemsource for the ListBox. I also used an ItemTemplate in my xaml code. Finally, I used the ReactiveUI suggested collection types instead of a just a simple ObservableCollection, and did a bit of fancy timed changes to the list so you can better see how that works.
see: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections.html
MainWindow.xaml:
<rxui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="MvvmSandbox.MainWindow"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                     xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
                     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmSandbox.ViewModels"
                     Title="MainWindow"
                     Width="200"
                     Height="250"
                     x:TypeArguments="vm:ListBoxViewModel"
                     mc:Ignorable="d">
  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="stringLB" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using ReactiveUI;
using MvvmSandbox.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmSandbox
{
  public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<ListBoxViewModel>
  {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      ViewModel = new ListBoxViewModel();

      this.WhenActivated(d => {
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.MyStrings,
          view => view.stringLB.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(d);
      });
    }
  }
}

ListBoxViewModel.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using DynamicData;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace MvvmSandbox.ViewModels
{
  public class ListBoxViewModel : ReactiveObject
  {
    private readonly SourceList<string> _myStrings;
    public readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> MyStrings;
    public ListBoxViewModel() {
      _myStrings = new SourceList<string>();

      _myStrings.Connect()
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Bind(out MyStrings)
        .Subscribe();

      // initial list
      _myStrings.Add("This is a test");

      // add items one sec at a time
      Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(3)
        .Select(i => $"This is test {i+1}")
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Subscribe(x => _myStrings.Add(x));

      // remove an item
      Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Skip(3)
        .Take(1)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Subscribe(x => _myStrings.RemoveAt(0));
    }
  }
}


Haha, you're much better at this than I am! I messed up my example, copied in the wrong classes... I'm surprised you were able to make heads or tails of it. I got it to work with your example, though - thank you so much, massive kudos!
